Vue.js: ordering of nested events
I am working on a search field component using Vue.js where I want to show a suggest box when an input field is focused and hide it when the input field loses focus. When a user clicks a suggestion it should appear in the search field.
However, this is not working as expected. The suggestion does not appear when it is selected from the drop down.
It suspect an issue with the ordering of event handlers - the dropdown is removed before it can change the model.
It also feels like my use of @focusin and @focusout is wonky, as the dropdown is part of the input container, so when I click on a suggestion it should not actually change focus.
I wrote a minimal example to reproduce the issue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const show = ref(false)
const model = ref('')

const setFocus = (on: boolean) => {
  // it works when I introduce a timeout before I change the value
  // setTimeout(() => {
  show.value = on
  // }, 100)
}
</script>

<template>
  <div id="container" @focusin="setFocus(true)" @focusout="setFocus(false)">
    <input
      class="input-field"
      type="text"
      placeholder="focus me"
      v-model="model"
    />
    <div id="conditional" v-if="show">
      <span @click="model = 'it works !'">click me</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.input-field {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
#conditional {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

I do not want to use setTimeout to introduce a delay obviously. Interestingly it does not work if I use nextTick() or a very small delay in the timeout.

I'm not sure what are focusin and focusout listeners (might just be a me lack of knowledge tho). I know about focus and blur tho, give those a try. You can also give a try to a few focus composables available here: https://vueuse.org/core/useFocus/#usefocus

Replace "click" with "mousedown". A timeout would be an acceptable workaround if you weren't able to do that

Thanks @EstusFlask , mousedown does fix the Problem! The reason is, that  mousedown which is fired before focusout. This explanation was originally posted here
(the timeout is not acceptable though, because while 100ms does the trick on my machine it might be different on slower devices).

@hwk I added it to the list of dupes. It would be acceptable with some perceptible delay, more like 200-500, still a workaround. The primary problem is not device speed but that "click" waits for mouse up
